# Scrapy - Activating an Item Pipeline component - ITEM_PIPELINES setting

Tags: python, scrapy, settings, pipeline

In scrapy documentation there is this information:

> **Activating an Item Pipeline component**
>
> To activate an Item Pipeline component you must add its class to the
>   ITEM_PIPELINES setting, like in the following example:
>
> ITEM_PIPELINES = {
>       'myproject.pipelines.PricePipeline': 300,
>       'myproject.pipelines.JsonWriterPipeline': 800, }
>
> The integer values you assign to classes in this setting determine the
>   order they run in- items go through pipelines from order number low to
>   high. It’s customary to define these numbers in the 0-1000 range.

I do not understand the last paragraph, mainly "determine the
 order they run in- items go through pipelines from order number low to
 high", can you explain in other words? that numbers are chosen because of what? in the range is 0-1000 how to choose the values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since a **dictionary in Python is an unordered collection** and `ITEM_PIPELINES` has to be a dictionary (as a lot of other settings, like, for example, `SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES`), you need to, somehow, define an order in which pipelines are applied. This is why you need to assign a number from 0 to 1000 to each pipeline you define.

FYI, if you look into Scrapy source, you'll find [`build_component_list()`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/utils/conf.py#L9) function which is called for each setting like `ITEM_PIPELINES` - it makes a list (ordered collection) out of the dictionary you define in `ITEM_PIPELINES` using dictionary values for sorting:

```
def build_component_list(base, custom):
    """Compose a component list based on a custom and base dict of components
    (typically middlewares or extensions), unless custom is already a list, in
    which case it's returned.
    """
    if isinstance(custom, (list, tuple)):
        return custom
    compdict = base.copy()
    compdict.update(custom)
    items = (x for x in six.iteritems(compdict) if x[1] is not None)
    return [x[0] for x in sorted(items, key=itemgetter(1))]
```

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html)

> ITEM_PIPELINES
>
> Default: {}
>
> A dict containing the item pipelines to use, and their orders. The
>   dict is empty by default order values are arbitrary but it’s customary
>   to define them in the 0-1000 range.